# the type or namespace name 'directx' does not exist in the namespace 'microsoft'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directx, directx-9

I have been trying to include DirectX in C sharp project (Visual Studio 2010).
I installed DirectX SDK and included the components as:

```
using Microsoft.DirectX;
using Microsoft.DirextX.Direct3D;
```

When I try to compile, I get the error: **the type or namespace name 'directx' does not exist in the namespace 'microsoft'**

Some blogs mentioned that I need to add 'reference' - Microsoft.DirectX under '.NET' tab. But I couldn't find it over there. Neither was any facility to add it to the tab.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was deprecated a long time ago.  The last Direct SDK that still has the managed wrappers is February 2010.  The download is [available here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180323042243/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10084).  You'll get to pick the references you are looking for after you install that one.

Better not to use it, no future, look at something like the open source SlimDX or SharpDX projects.

Comment: Thanks. Will go through SlimDX to see if it can be worked out.

Answer (score 1):

There are various reasons why a dll would not appear on the .Net tab.There is specific registry configuration that makes certain dlls to appear on the .Net tab.

Alternatively use the browse option to add the dll reference manually to your project.

**Project >> Add Reference**

[image]

Comment: In this case the reason is that the assemblies don't exist anywhere on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to add reference for `Directx` in `C#` Program :

- Go to the solution explorer
- Click references
- Click add reference
- Click Browse
  Go to : "`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\1.0.2902.0\`" 
  *usually this is the place of `Directx` Files located. This can be change with the installation of `.net`.
- Select your `DirectX` package.

example :

```
(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\1.0.2902.0\Microsoft.DirectX.dll)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way i have find. First you need to install DXSDK (i have June2010 and SDK for Windows 7). Go to "Add refference" dialog press "Browse" , go to something like this "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\1.0.2902.0" or "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Managed DirectX\v9.02.2904" then choose proper dll for example - Microsoft.DirectX.dll. So you can add "using Microsoft.DirectX" directive to your project.