# Visual Studio 2019 DirectX using directive

Tags: c#, windows, directx, direct3d

I am currently trying to follow the Microsoft docs tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms920749(v=msdn.10) on how to use Direct3D but there is no Microsoft.DirectX name space in .net framework or core. I have looked at many other articles discussing the mater and all reference VS 2010. My question is that is there any platform that contains this or an other better tutorial or way to get that assembly reference in VS 2019? I am using win Forms but I am willing to use wpf or any other app type.

Comment: Short answer it has been deprecated for a long time. Link to other stack overflow answer of same question but more in depth below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157290/the-type-or-namespace-name-directx-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you trying to use is no longer there. [More info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_DirectX).

In modern Windows, easiest way to proceed is UWP + SharpDX. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25458388/126995) for a starting point. This assumes you want to render your 3D content at refresh rate of the monitor; may or may not be a good idea, depends on your requirements.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted thanks.

Comment: See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-and-net/)